# Terrible Sound Quality with Sony SRS-BTX300

Tags: sound, bluetooth

I've paired my Sony SRS-BTX300 speaker with Ubuntu 15.04 (Dell Inspiron 5000) but the sound quality is horrible. I've troubleshot that it's not the speaker itself, and also I've paired with another bluetooth speaker in the house and that one sounds fine. I've fiddled with all the sound settings. Does this mean that the Sony is not compatible?
Any advice would be great. 
Thanks,
June

Comment: So are you saying that after pairing with the Sony speaker you can't change it to A2DP in sound settings?

Comment: I can and I tried that, and it made no difference in the sound quality.